# How to apply for loop to container in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to run PHP code in WAMP server using MySQL.  I am creating one container, 
I don't know how many containers I need. Somehow I have the count of containers generated dynamically.

I want as many containers as count. I want to apply the for loop to the below code based on count of containers.

Also I need to create CSS container classes based on count.

In the query where i am using where clause(Where Entity='ATA'), i have array of data to apply in where clause, here i have shown only one(ATA), i need the containers based on count.

```
<form>
<div id="container"> 

    <div id="content">
    <!-- all you need with Tablecloth is a regular, well formed table. No need for id's, class names... --> 
    <table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr >
                <th class="lightcolor" style="width:60px; height:30px;"><h2>Server Name</h2></th>
                <th class="lightcolor" style="width:60px; height:30px;"><h2>IP Address</h2></th>

            </tr>
<?php       
            $user_name = "root";
            $password = "";
            $database = "atssautomationgnoc";
            $server = "localhost";
            $con = mysqli_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
            $db_found = mysqli_select_db($con,$database);
            $query = "SELECT Servername,IPAddress FROM t_applicationstatus Where Entity='ATA'  order by FIELD(LiveStatus,'RTO','OK')";
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
            $Names = array();
            if($result == FALSE)
            {
                die(mysql_error());
            }
            $i=0;


           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
           {
              $rowsA[] = $row;
           }


            foreach($rowsA as $row)
            {
              $rowsA[$i]=$row['Servername'];
               $rowsA[$i] = $row['IPAddress'];

               echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td id=health>" ;
               echo $row['Servername'] ;
               echo " </td>";
              echo "<td  id=health>" ;
              echo $row['IPAddress'];
              echo " </td>";
              echo " </td>";
              echo "</tr>";
            }
?>  
    </table>    
       </div>   
    </form>
```

Comment: Why do you overwrite the `$rowsA[$i]`? And where do you incrase `$i`? And the `id` should be unique in HTML.

Comment: yes i know id should be unique , but i need different containers dynamically based on count , the count is not fixed , How can i do that

Comment: in query i am applying where clause(Where entity='ATA'),  in where condition i have different number of data, based on all data i need to execute query and contianers for all different

Answer (score 0):

Say, all of the criterias you wish to specify in where clause are stored in array `$entityArr`.
You then should add an extra loop on top of the `<table>` element. Try the following code.

```
<div id="container"> 
    <div id="content">
<?php

$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "atssautomationgnoc";
$server = "localhost";
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysqli_select_db($con,$database);

$entityArr = array("ATA", "ANOTHER", "AND_ANOTHER"); 
$rowsA = array(); //define rowsA
foreach ($entityArr as $entity)
{
?>
    <table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <th class="lightcolor" style="width:60px; height:30px;"><h2>Server Name</h2></th>
                <th class="lightcolor" style="width:60px; height:30px;"><h2>IP Address</h2></th>
            </tr>
<?php       
            //use $entity below in where condition
            $query = "SELECT Servername,IPAddress FROM t_applicationstatus Where Entity='".$entity."'  order by FIELD(LiveStatus,'RTO','OK')";
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
            $Names = array();
            if($result == FALSE)
            {
                die(mysql_error());
            }

           //clear array
           unset($rowsA);
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
           {
              $rowsA[] = $row;
           }


            foreach($rowsA as $row)
            {
              $rowsA[$i]=$row['Servername']; //You'd better comment this line out
              $rowsA[$i] = $row['IPAddress']; //And this one

              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>" ;
              echo $row['Servername'] ;
              echo " </td>";
              echo "<td>" ;
              echo $row['IPAddress'];
              echo " </td>";
              echo " </td>";//This is extra, simply remove this line 
              echo "</tr>";
            }
?>  
    </table>    
<?php
}
?>
    </div> <!-- close #content -->
</div> <!-- close #container -->
```

There are various ways to do this, especially without executing sql statements in the loop. Hope that helps.

Comment: its giving the following error when I run for loop:-                 undefined variable:rowsA

Comment: I've updated the answer. Simply add `$rowsA = array();` before foreach and `unset($rowsA);` before while as shown in the code sample. Let me know if it works or not. PS: Can't run php on my computer at the moment, so I can't test it.